# application.Documents.Add(filePath) returns null when VBA code interfering

Tags: vba, ms-word, vsto

Our product uses VSTO (C#) to create a new document from a template:

```
Document document =_application.Documents.Add(filePath);
```

The 'document' variable will contain the reference to the document object.
Now we have a customer that has a template installed in the Word startup folder that contains VBA code that creates a document uses that document and removes it.

```
'' Module contents
Dim oAppClass As New ThisApplication

Public Sub AutoExec()
    Set oAppClass.oApp = Word.Application
End Sub


'' Class module contents
Public WithEvents oApp As Word.Application

Private Sub oApp_NewDocument(ByVal Doc As Document)
    Dim oDoc As Document
    Set oDoc = Documents.Add
    ' do something with the document
    oDoc.Close
End Sub
```

When this vba code is in place, the C# code (at the top of the question) return null instead of the document that just was created. So the document is actually created in Word and the application.Documents collection contains an extra document, but the 'document' variable is null.

I'm looking for a proper solution of getting a reference to the newly created document.

I can fetch a list of currently opened documents before adding the new document and fetch the list afterward, compare them and find the new document. But if the VBA code creates a new document without closing it, there would be 2 new documents. Than I still wouldn't know what the document is, that I created from the C# code.

So is there a way of determining what document I created from C# code in this situation?

Comment: The documents collections in VSTO and VBA are completely separate and to my knowledge there's no way to exchange data between them (to make them "equivalent"). I'd suggest that the C# code save the document to a temporary (read: obscure but static filename and path) file and then the VBA code can access and open that document once it's created.

Comment: I am aware that the setup is kind of strange. But the VBA code is out of our hand. The customer has some scenario why they need that. But I was surprised that the C# code all of a sudden doesn't get a document returned, but a null value.

Comment: The customer's VBA isn't making any sense to me. When I read that, it's telling me that when a new document is generated this macro is creating *another* new document - without specifying a particular template. I'd also want to see the rest of that code, to understand what happens with the first of these documents (the `Doc` parameter). I'm betting it gets closed somewhere in there... Anyway, that's responsible for "losing" the document your add-in creates...

Comment: (And by the way, the comments are incorrect: the standard module is the top part; the class the bottom part. And I assume the class name is `ThisApplication`?)

Comment: @CindyMeister, Thanx I edited the comments. The VBA is also not making sense to me ;-) This piece of code is what we know of and is able to reproduce the scenario. I think the solution of m40_tim  can help me. Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"is there a way of determining what document I created from C# code in this situation?"

Yes. Query the document's `AttachedTemplate` property. If the VBA code in the startup template is as it appears in your question for any document that it creates `.AttachedTemplate.Name` will return `Normal.dotm`, whereas your document will be attached to the template that you pass in as `filePath`.

By comparing `.AttachedTemplate.FullName` to `filePath` you should get a match.